# Nextjs after deploy Link refresh page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Use nextjs last version, when i deploy(use firebase) and try to navigate the page is completely refreshed, that not happen in local.

```
const CustomLink = ({ children, page, ...props }) => (
<Link
  className={`...`}
  onClick={(event) => {
    if (props.disabled) event.preventDefault();
  }}
  href={page}
>
  {children}
</Link>
```

);

that's how i use it

```
<CustomLink page="/xxx">Home</CustomLink>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does it happen if you directly use `<Link>` too?

Comment: @brc-dd yes! :/

Comment: I have same problem. When deployed to firebase. Each time page refresh when navigating through Link. this was not the case before. Did you get the answer ?

Comment: check this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6141) in github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 0):

try to preserve props

```
 <Link
  className={`...`} {...props}
  onClick={(event) => {
    if (props.disabled) event.preventDefault();
  }}
  href={page}
>
  {children}
</Link>
```